# Selenium python xpath contains issues

Tags: python, selenium, automation, beautifulsoup

Slowly teaching myself some automation using selenium. Made a small little program to automatically check out a product that is going to release online. Everything looks to be working perfectly except the program will only work if I type the exact product name into it.

First I have this user input:

```
Productname = raw_input("Pleae enter the name of your product:")
```

This is the xpath click script that I am using that I believe is meant to work with keywords and will not need the exact product name.`

```
browser.refresh()
element = WebDriverWait(browser, 3).until(
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(text(),'" + Productname + "')]")));
element.click();
```

This is a snippet of the html where product names are located bellow

[Html snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRwPl.png)

Would love some assistance. Have learnt so much during this little project and this seems to be the only issue I can't resolve.

Regards,

-Julian

Comment: Try this -- "//a/img[contains(@alt,'" + Productname + "')]"

Comment: Still appears to require an exact product name. For example the product I am testing with is Palace Drury P3 Deck 8.3. If enter Palace Drury Deck 8.3 it will fail or any other variation. The problem is I don't know the exact format the text will be in when the product is loaded onto the website

Comment: @JulianJames Can you consider showcasing your work and the relevant HTML DOM in the Question area please? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try following xpath :

```
//div[@class='grid-product-info']
```

Hope it will help you.